# gpg-agent forwarding: inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: gpg-agent

I'm trying to setup gpg-agent forwarding in order to use pass (https://www.passwordstore.org) via ssh.

gpg version 2.2.9 both on local and remote hosts, installed by instructions:
https://gist.github.com/vt0r/a2f8c0bcb1400131ff51

#### On local machine

$HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf

`extra-socket /home/mickey/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.remote`

Reload agent

`echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent`

Export public key

`gpg --export -a mickey > mickey.gpg`

Sign test data

`echo "test" | gpg2 --encrypt -r mickey > out.gpg`

Send public key and signed data

`scp *.gpg REMOTE_HOST:`

Create ssh session with reverse forwarding

`ssh -R /run/user/1002/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:/home/mickey/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.remote -o "StreamLocalBindUnlink=yes" REMOTE_HOST`

#### On remote machine

Import public key

`gpg --import mickey.gpg`

Trust this key ultimately

`gpg --edit-key mickey`

`trust 5 quit`

Try to decrypt

`gpg --decrypt -v out.gpg`

Output

```
gpg: public key is FED6243A3325C554
gpg: connection to agent is in restricted mode
gpg: using subkey FED6243A3325C554 instead of primary key 9E2ED69A02554504
gpg: using subkey FED6243A3325C554 instead of primary key 9E2ED69A02554504
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID FED6243A3325C554, created 2018-07-23
      "mickey"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

So, agent socket forwarding is working, seems there are some problems with pinentry program. Could not find anything that worked for me in google.

#### UPD

Tried to add `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-tty` to gpg-agent.conf, new error:

```
gpg: public key decryption failed: Invalid IPC response
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Answer (score 138, accepted):

It happens when GPG is confused where to read input from. Simply configuring it to look for input from tty (the terminal connected to standard input) fixes it:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

Comment: I used just `ssh -X` and it worked. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: fishshell: `set -x GPG_TTY (tty) && <your command>`

Comment: python: os.environ["GPG_TTY"] = os.ttyname(sys.stdin.fileno())

Answer (score 42):

[This method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55032706/139040) does not work when you are inside an LXC container. Instead, add this to `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`:

```
use-agent 
pinentry-mode loopback
```

Then add this to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

```
allow-loopback-pinentry
```

Then restart the agent with `echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent`.

([source](https://d.sb/2016/11/gpg-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-errors))

Comment: Can you specify on where are the files you edited? Are the in the LXC container or in the machine you SSH from?

Comment: @Oz123 I am sorry I do not recall. Try the target (LXC) first. Pls lmk so I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: If this error is happening because you're calling `gpg` from a daemon, it'll be necessary to add `no-tty` and `batch` to `gpg.conf`.

Comment: Worked for me when signing git commits inside ubuntu WSL

Comment: I get an error `sorry working in batch mode` please advise

Answer (score 6):

When running gpg from a script, the --batch argument must be provided.

Comment: I get an error sorry working in batch mode please advise